# I don't find ProxyTicketReceptor in CAS jars

Tags: java, spring, single-sign-on, cas

I am using **CAS** server and client jars with version *3.4.10*.

> - cas-server-core-3.4.10.jar
> - cas-client-core-3.2.0.jar

I want to user  proxy granting ticket approach for allowing external web app to access to our web application. How ever I could not find the `ProxyTicketReceptor` class.

Do I need to add any additional jars?

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That class only exists in super old versions of the CAS Java client.

This might help better:
https://github.com/UniconLabs/cas-sample-java-webapp/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

You probably should update your version of the CAS client to match that example/link (and your CAS server since 3.x is EOL)

Comment: Hi Misagh, Thanks for your response. Basically what I am looking for is from an external application(which does not use CAS for authentication) to be able to get a PGT from CAS Server for a Service (web application) and invoke the sevice or URL with that Ticket. Is this possible to achieve. I don't want the login screen to appear when external app request a ticket from CAS server,

Comment: If the external app does not support CAS and has no other API for authN, your best chance is to replay the password back to the app via some sort of intermediary. Nothing else would work.